# How do I make a button fill the screen (in width) using relative layout?

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I am new to android development and I want to make my button cover the WHOLE width of the page with no space on either side. I have researched this and using android weight doesn't work.

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="98dp"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
         android:text="@string/hello_world"
         android:textColor="#228496"
         android:textSize="14sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/categories"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
         android:onClick="Categories"
         android:text="@string/title_activity_categories"
         android:textColor="#228496"
         android:textSize="21sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/feedback"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/categories"
         android:layout_below="@+id/categories"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
         android:onClick="feedback"
         android:text="@string/Feedback"
         android:textColor="#228496"
         android:textSize="21sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your layout looks correct.  Depending on your theme/styles you might have some default margin on the button.  Try adding android:layout_margin="0dp" below android:layout_marginTop="14dp" . Also, your buttonpress drawable, if it's an image, might have blank space in the png that you need to crop out.

Comment: Still some kind of border... i have implement all these methods...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Here is the screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: I have tried it but there is still a border to the left and right :(

Comment: That might be the activity's horizontal/vertical margin. Check */res/values/dimens.xml* file for that.

Comment: i have changed it to 0dp margins then what should i do?

Comment: If the unwanted padding still exists after rerunning, can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

In light of you still having a small amount of padding on the buttons, you also might try a small negative space inside the button xml like done below (from http://swengineeringnotebook.blogspot.com/2012/12/removing-borders-around-buttons-in.html)

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-3dip" />
```

Answer (score 1):

U just try below code:-

```
     <Button
     android:id="@+id/categories"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
     android:onClick="Categories"
     android:text="@string/title_activity_categories"
     android:textColor="#228496"
     android:textSize="21sp" />
```

Comment: Just a note, unless you are targeting API 7 and below, you will want to switch `fill_parent` to `match_parent` since `fill_parent` was deprecated in API 8.

Comment: I have tried it but there is still a really small border which is frustrating :(

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with android:layout_weight="1" in relative layout items when the layouts are simple.